# Compact set instead of closed set for $m(E\setminus A)<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

For Lebesgue measure, we know that it is regular, and for any $\epsilon$ and Borel set $E$, there exists a closed set $A\subset E$ s.t.
$m(E\setminus A)<\epsilon$
Can we replace closed set with compact set?

Comment: Consider ther sets $A_n=A\cap [-n,n]$.

Comment: You can iff $m(E) < \infty.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $E$ be the real numbers. Then whatever compact set $A$ you remove from $E$, $m(E\backslash A)=\infty$ right?